# Using Java RegEx how can I return only exact matches?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string containing a fairly large amount of text that I want to search through for pattern matches. For each match I find, I want to extract it from the input string and store it in a List or a String[] for further sorting.

To this end, I'm trying to use Java regular expressions to search for the pattern I want, then print these matches to my console. But I'm clearly not doing something right with my RegEx because not only are my matches being returned, but everything that was found from the beginning of the input string, through to the final match for my RegEx is being returned as well.

I am desperately trying to find a way to just return my RegEx matches, without anything else! Can anyone offer a viable solution? I would be very thankful because I'm stumped at the moment!

For a quick look at what I'm doing, see this saved RegEx: [Search for 30 minute wait times](https://regex101.com/r/Ds1Ro7/2)

Otherwise, here's my code and the entire input string I'm trying to sort, as a good example of the data I'm dealing with:

```
final String regex = "(name=\"(.*?) 30 Minute Wait,)";
    final String input1 = "name=\"Barnstormer, Fantasyland, 05 Minute Wait,name=\"Big Thunder Mountain Railroad, Frontierland, 05 Minute Wait,name=\"Celebrity Spotlight, Echo Lake, 05 Minute Wait,name=\"DINOSAUR, DinoLand U.S.A., 05 Minute Wait,name=\"Expedition Everest - Legend of the Forbidden Mountain, Asia, 05 Minute Wait,name=\"Gran Fiesta Tour StarringThree Caballeros, World Showcase, 05 Minute Wait,name=\"Great Movie Ride, Hollywood Boulevard, 05 Minute Wait,name=\"Mad Tea Party, Fantasyland, 05 Minute Wait,name=\"Meet Chewbacca at Star Wars Launch Bay, Animation Courtyard, 05 Minute Wait,name=\"Seas with Nemo & Friends, Future World, 05 Minute Wait,name=\"Star Wars Launch Bay Theater, Animation Courtyard, 05 Minute Wait,name=\"TriceraTop Spin, DinoLand U.S.A., 05 Minute Wait,name=\"Buzz Lightyear's Space Ranger Spin, Tomorrowland, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Dumbo the Flying Elephant, Fantasyland, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Encounter Kylo Ren at Star Wars Launch Bay, Animation Courtyard, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"it's a small world, Fantasyland, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Kilimanjaro Safaris, Africa, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Magic Carpets of Aladdin, Adventureland, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Many Adventures of Winnie the Pooh, Fantasyland, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Mickey and Minnie Starring in Red Carpet Dreams, Commissary Lane, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Mickey's PhilharMagic, Fantasyland, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Muppet*Vision 3D, Muppet Courtyard, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Pirates of the Caribbean, Adventureland, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Primeval Whirl, DinoLand U.S.A., 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Soarin', Future World, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Spaceship Earth, Future World, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Star Tours –Adventures Continue, Echo Lake, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Toy Story Mania!, Pixar Place, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Twilight Zone Tower of Terror™, Sunset Boulevard, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Under the Sea ~ Journey ofLittle Mermaid, Fantasyland, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Jungle Cruise, Adventureland, 15 Minute Wait,name=\"Mission: SPACE, Future World, 15 Minute Wait,name=\"Rock 'n' Roller Coaster Starring Aerosmith, Sunset Boulevard, 15 Minute Wait,name=\"Splash Mountain, Frontierland, 15 Minute Wait,name=\"Astro Orbiter, Tomorrowland, 20 Minute Wait,name=\"Meet Disney Pals at the Epcot Character Spot, Future World, 20 Minute Wait,name=\"Monsters, Inc. Laugh Floor, Tomorrowland, 20 Minute Wait,name=\"Meet Rapunzel and Tiana at Princess Fairytale Hall, Fantasyland, 25 Minute Wait,name=\"Space Mountain, Tomorrowland, 25 Minute Wait,name=\"Enchanted Tales with Belle, Fantasyland, 30 Minute Wait,name=\"Meet Cinderella and Elena at Princess Fairytale Hall, Fantasyland, 30 Minute Wait,name=\"Meet Tinker Bell at Town Square Theater, Main Street, U.S.A., 30 Minute Wait,name=\"Peter Pan's Flight, Fantasyland, 30 Minute Wait,name=\"Test Track, Future World, 30 Minute Wait,name=\"Meet Anna and Elsa at Royal Sommerhus, World Showcase, 40 Minute Wait,name=\"Tomorrowland Speedway, Tomorrowland, 40 Minute Wait,name=\"Frozen Ever After, World Showcase, 45 Minute Wait,name=\"Meet Mickey Mouse at Town Square Theater, Main Street, U.S.A., 55 Minute Wait,name=\"Meet Ariel at Her Grotto, Fantasyland, 65 Minute Wait,name=\"Seven Dwarfs Mine Train, Fantasyland, 80 Minute Wait,name=\"Haunted Mansion, Liberty Square, Temporarily Closed,name=\"Kali River Rapids, Asia, Temporarily Closed\n";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input1);

    //Create a List String for storing the Wait Time matches that we find
    List<String> waitTimesSorted = new ArrayList<String>();

    //Create a loop that the matcher uses to search through the input string for our Wait Times
    while (matcher.find()) {
        //Add the matching wait times we find to a List String     
        waitTimesSorted.add(matcher.group());              
    }

    //Print our matches to the console
    System.out.println(waitTimesSorted);
```

The output of this finds my 30 minute wait times, but returns everything that was found in the input string up to my matches as well!

```
[name="Barnstormer, Fantasyland, 05 Minute Wait,name="Big Thunder Mountain Railroad, Frontierland, 05 Minute Wait,name="Celebrity Spotlight, Echo Lake, 05 Minute Wait,name="DINOSAUR, DinoLand U.S.A., 05 Minute Wait,name="Expedition Everest - Legend of the Forbidden Mountain, Asia, 05 Minute Wait,name="Gran Fiesta Tour StarringThree Caballeros, World Showcase, 05 Minute Wait,name="Great Movie Ride, Hollywood Boulevard, 05 Minute Wait,name="Mad Tea Party, Fantasyland, 05 Minute Wait,name="Meet Chewbacca at Star Wars Launch Bay, Animation Courtyard, 05 Minute Wait,name="Seas with Nemo & Friends, Future World, 05 Minute Wait,name="Star Wars Launch Bay Theater, Animation Courtyard, 05 Minute Wait,name="TriceraTop Spin, DinoLand U.S.A., 05 Minute Wait,name="Buzz Lightyear's Space Ranger Spin, Tomorrowland, 10 Minute Wait,name="Dumbo the Flying Elephant, Fantasyland, 10 Minute Wait,name="Encounter Kylo Ren at Star Wars Launch Bay, Animation Courtyard, 10 Minute Wait,name="it's a small world, Fantasyland, 10 Minute Wait,name="Kilimanjaro Safaris, Africa, 10 Minute Wait,name="Magic Carpets of Aladdin, Adventureland, 10 Minute Wait,name="Many Adventures of Winnie the Pooh, Fantasyland, 10 Minute Wait,name="Mickey and Minnie Starring in Red Carpet Dreams, Commissary Lane, 10 Minute Wait,name="Mickey's PhilharMagic, Fantasyland, 10 Minute Wait,name="Muppet*Vision 3D, Muppet Courtyard, 10 Minute Wait,name="Pirates of the Caribbean, Adventureland, 10 Minute Wait,name="Primeval Whirl, DinoLand U.S.A., 10 Minute Wait,name="Soarin', Future World, 10 Minute Wait,name="Spaceship Earth, Future World, 10 Minute Wait,name="Star Tours –Adventures Continue, Echo Lake, 10 Minute Wait,name="Toy Story Mania!, Pixar Place, 10 Minute Wait,name="Twilight Zone Tower of Terror™, Sunset Boulevard, 10 Minute Wait,name="Under the Sea ~ Journey ofLittle Mermaid, Fantasyland, 10 Minute Wait,name="Jungle Cruise, Adventureland, 15 Minute Wait,name="Mission: SPACE, Future World, 15 Minute Wait,name="Rock 'n' Roller Coaster Starring Aerosmith, Sunset Boulevard, 15 Minute Wait,name="Splash Mountain, Frontierland, 15 Minute Wait,name="Astro Orbiter, Tomorrowland, 20 Minute Wait,name="Meet Disney Pals at the Epcot Character Spot, Future World, 20 Minute Wait,name="Monsters, Inc. Laugh Floor, Tomorrowland, 20 Minute Wait,name="Meet Rapunzel and Tiana at Princess Fairytale Hall, Fantasyland, 25 Minute Wait,name="Space Mountain, Tomorrowland, 25 Minute Wait,name="Enchanted Tales with Belle, Fantasyland, 30 Minute Wait,, name="Meet Cinderella and Elena at Princess Fairytale Hall, Fantasyland, 30 Minute Wait,, name="Meet Tinker Bell at Town Square Theater, Main Street, U.S.A., 30 Minute Wait,, name="Peter Pan's Flight, Fantasyland, 30 Minute Wait,, name="Test Track, Future World, 30 Minute Wait,]
```

What I want to have returned is something like this:

```
name="Enchanted Tales with Belle, Fantasyland, 30 Minute Wait,, name="Meet Cinderella and Elena at Princess Fairytale Hall, Fantasyland, 30 Minute Wait,, name="Meet Tinker Bell at Town Square Theater, Main Street, U.S.A., 30 Minute Wait,, name="Peter Pan's Flight, Fantasyland, 30 Minute Wait,, name="Test Track, Future World, 30 Minute Wait,]
```

Is there any way to only get back what I'm searching for?

I do need the *exact* matches for the wait times (am using 30 minutes here as a single example) because I'm trying to break the wait time groups up by their wait times (5 minute wait, 10 minute wait, 15 minute wait, etc), and then do sorting on them to ensure that each group is in alphabetical order. So, I don't look for generic digits in my RegEx, I am being very specific about the wait times and actually have an array of expected wait times that I work through to generate my RegEx, but that's another matter and not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `.*?` will walk across any other `name="` too, making it match too much.

To prevent that, a simple exclusion of either `=` or `"` will prevent that.

Also, you don't need to capture the entire matched expression. That is done anyway as capture group 0.

So, regex `name="([^"]*?) 30 Minute Wait,` will do it.
As a Java string, that would be `"name=\"([^\"]*?) 30 Minute Wait,"`.

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ijG8Xr/1).

Comment: nice answer, but you don't need grouping here, Just   name="[^"]*? 30 Minute Wait,

Comment: @MikeAdamenko You're right, but I'm assuming OP wanted to capture that for some reason, so I left it in.

Comment: Andreas! Bro! Wow, that did the trick! OMG, thank you! I've been bashing my head against a brick wall for weeks trying to get this right! Wow! You have no idea how incredibly helpful this is to me! I am deeply thankful to you for taking the time to respond! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Thank you to everyone who responded! I am very grateful to all of you! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Andreas

i have shorter version of valid regexp `name=[^=]*30 Minute Wait,`

see https://regex101.com/r/ijG8Xr/2

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your regex is that you placed the "capturing groups" around the whole input, and calling `group()` with an index returns the full match, including `.*`, which means anything before the wait time.

If you change your regex to `"name=\"(.*?) (30 Minute Wait),"` and call `matcher.group(2)`, it will return you `"30 Minute Wait"`.

Look at the Javadoc of the `group(int)` method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-int-.

Oh, and you might want to replace the `"30"` in your regex with `"\\d+"`, in order to find any numbers, and not just 30.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to skip the characters that you don't want in your matches, otherwise it will match from the beginning of the string forwards. Try something like `.*?(name=\"(.*?) 30 Minute Wait,)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andreas, here is the correct RegEx to get whatever pattern I'm searching for, and nothing else:

```
final String regex = "([^\"]*?) 30 Minute Wait,";
final String input1 = "name=\"Barnstormer, Fantasyland, 05 Minute Wait,name=\"Big Thunder Mountain Railroad, Frontierland, 05 Minute Wait,name=\"Celebrity Spotlight, Echo Lake, 05 Minute Wait,name=\"DINOSAUR, DinoLand U.S.A., 05 Minute Wait,name=\"Expedition Everest - Legend of the Forbidden Mountain, Asia, 05 Minute Wait,name=\"Gran Fiesta Tour StarringThree Caballeros, World Showcase, 05 Minute Wait,name=\"Great Movie Ride, Hollywood Boulevard, 05 Minute Wait,name=\"Mad Tea Party, Fantasyland, 05 Minute Wait,name=\"Meet Chewbacca at Star Wars Launch Bay, Animation Courtyard, 05 Minute Wait,name=\"Seas with Nemo & Friends, Future World, 05 Minute Wait,name=\"Star Wars Launch Bay Theater, Animation Courtyard, 05 Minute Wait,name=\"TriceraTop Spin, DinoLand U.S.A., 05 Minute Wait,name=\"Buzz Lightyear's Space Ranger Spin, Tomorrowland, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Dumbo the Flying Elephant, Fantasyland, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Encounter Kylo Ren at Star Wars Launch Bay, Animation Courtyard, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"it's a small world, Fantasyland, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Kilimanjaro Safaris, Africa, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Magic Carpets of Aladdin, Adventureland, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Many Adventures of Winnie the Pooh, Fantasyland, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Mickey and Minnie Starring in Red Carpet Dreams, Commissary Lane, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Mickey's PhilharMagic, Fantasyland, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Muppet*Vision 3D, Muppet Courtyard, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Pirates of the Caribbean, Adventureland, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Primeval Whirl, DinoLand U.S.A., 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Soarin', Future World, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Spaceship Earth, Future World, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Star Tours –Adventures Continue, Echo Lake, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Toy Story Mania!, Pixar Place, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Twilight Zone Tower of Terror™, Sunset Boulevard, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Under the Sea ~ Journey ofLittle Mermaid, Fantasyland, 10 Minute Wait,name=\"Jungle Cruise, Adventureland, 15 Minute Wait,name=\"Mission: SPACE, Future World, 15 Minute Wait,name=\"Rock 'n' Roller Coaster Starring Aerosmith, Sunset Boulevard, 15 Minute Wait,name=\"Splash Mountain, Frontierland, 15 Minute Wait,name=\"Astro Orbiter, Tomorrowland, 20 Minute Wait,name=\"Meet Disney Pals at the Epcot Character Spot, Future World, 20 Minute Wait,name=\"Monsters, Inc. Laugh Floor, Tomorrowland, 20 Minute Wait,name=\"Meet Rapunzel and Tiana at Princess Fairytale Hall, Fantasyland, 25 Minute Wait,name=\"Space Mountain, Tomorrowland, 25 Minute Wait,name=\"Enchanted Tales with Belle, Fantasyland, 30 Minute Wait,name=\"Meet Cinderella and Elena at Princess Fairytale Hall, Fantasyland, 30 Minute Wait,name=\"Meet Tinker Bell at Town Square Theater, Main Street, U.S.A., 30 Minute Wait,name=\"Peter Pan's Flight, Fantasyland, 30 Minute Wait,name=\"Test Track, Future World, 30 Minute Wait,name=\"Meet Anna and Elsa at Royal Sommerhus, World Showcase, 40 Minute Wait,name=\"Tomorrowland Speedway, Tomorrowland, 40 Minute Wait,name=\"Frozen Ever After, World Showcase, 45 Minute Wait,name=\"Meet Mickey Mouse at Town Square Theater, Main Street, U.S.A., 55 Minute Wait,name=\"Meet Ariel at Her Grotto, Fantasyland, 65 Minute Wait,name=\"Seven Dwarfs Mine Train, Fantasyland, 80 Minute Wait,name=\"Haunted Mansion, Liberty Square, Temporarily Closed,name=\"Kali River Rapids, Asia, Temporarily Closed\n";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input1);

        //Create a List String for storing the Wait Time matches that we find
        List<String> waitTimesSorted = new ArrayList<String>();

        //Create a loop that the matcher uses to search through the input string for our Wait Times
        while (matcher.find()) {
            //Add the matching wait times we find to a List String     
            waitTimesSorted.add(matcher.group());              
        }

        //Print our matches to the console
        System.out.println(waitTimesSorted);
```

This will return the following results--which is precisely what I wanted!

```
[Enchanted Tales with Belle, Fantasyland, 30 Minute Wait,, Meet Cinderella and Elena at Princess Fairytale Hall, Fantasyland, 30 Minute Wait,, Meet Tinker Bell at Town Square Theater, Main Street, U.S.A., 30 Minute Wait,, Peter Pan's Flight, Fantasyland, 30 Minute Wait,, Test Track, Future World, 30 Minute Wait,]
```

Thanks again everyone!